# Can you get rich snippets to show on homepage?

Tags: rich-snippets, homepage

I have a home page that is a landing page for a software product. I have read that you can't get rich snippets to show for the homepage.

Is there tricks or alternatives to get the rich snippets to show?

Would a 301 redirect help any, or am I out of luck?

Comment: What type of snippet are you trying to show? What would you want to redirect that you think would help?

Answer (score 1):

do you have a one-pager? in general its not a good idea to make a startpage a landing page. make any subpage to your product page, like yoursite.com/productpage, then there will be no problem to implement any structured data generating rich snippets.

Comment: Why is it not a good idea to make a startpage a landing page?

Comment: its not a good idea to make a startpage a _landing page for product_. the startpage serves normally as a router, for distribution of visitors. i mean, startpage should be optimized for (generic, or brand, or product category) keywords, but not for (a sole) product keywords.

Comment: @Evgeniy Good advice that everyone should remember. I just posted an answer on another question and echoed some of the same advice. Great minds think alike! (this means you are in trouble...)